# Reading 2 integers from a file in c

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

My code requires me to open up a file.
the first line of the file contains 2 integers between 1 and 1000.
I must read these 2 numbers, use them to create a 2D array corresponding to those numbers 
(e.g. 50,200 is - array[50][200]).
After i have created this array, i have to read the rest of the file and store the data (which is set up in a grid of the dimensions of the 2 numbers).

What is the best way to go about this. I thought about doing a getline and then doing a for loop to append the chars to row then column and then converting to int, but my compiler kept coming up with errors.

Comment: Can you provide the code you used that produced that error? There are many approaches to this and it would be best to help guide you from seeing your approach to the problem.

Comment: i deleted it as i got frustrated. i was just wondering if this is a good method to do it, or am i overlooking some really simple method?

Comment: I provided a general approach below -- it could have been much more tailored to your exact approach provided you still had the code. I hope it can be of some use to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the file binary or text?  If binary, use fread, it will let you read the raw bytes easily.  if its text use fscanf

Comment: its in text as the first line is 2 integers and the rest are composed of the following: @ . / \ =

Comment: fscanf worked perfectly, thank-you, i knew it was something super simple

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is *always* of this form (a little unclear):

```
2,4
aaaa
b  b
```

... then an approach would be to read in the dimensions of your matrix (number of rows, number of columns) and then follow that up by reading each element of the matrix one character at a time. It would be something along the lines of this:

```
int rows = getchar();

// Skip ','.
getchar();

int cols = getchar();

int arr[ rows ][ cols ];
int r = 0;
int c = 0;

for ( int byte = getchar(); byte != EOF; byte = getchar(), c++ ) {
  if ( c == cols ) {
    c = 0;
    r++;
  }

  arr[ r ][ c ] = byte;
}
```

... and you would need to pipe the input file to your program as follows:

```
./program.out < input.txt
```

**Remark:** This is tailored to your *specific* problem-set, it would not work if: the input is not guaranteed to populate the entire array, the input is a bad size, overflow of dimensions, etc. (many issues) - so be sure to account for those.